# Find the fourier series representation of a function

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

> Consider the function 
>   $f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{\pi}{2}+x & & x \in (-\pi, 0] \\
> \frac{\pi}{2}-x & & x \in (0, \pi]\\
> \end{cases}$
>   extended 2$\pi$ periodically to $\mathbb{R}$. Calculate $a_0, a_n, b_n$

I understand how to work out a fourier series but I am unsure what to set for $f(x)$ due to the way its set out.

Would I have $a_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\pi}{2}+x dx$ due to splitting it into odd and even parts?

Comment: you would have two integrals. One for the first interval, with its own function, and another one for the second interval.

Comment: @Med so it would just be as simple as $a_0= \frac{1}{2\pi} ( \int_{-\pi}^{0} \frac{\pi}{2}+x dx + \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\pi}{2}-x dx )$

Comment: yes, in general, this is the simple way to look at it. your answer for a0 is 2*(pi)^2, which is different.

Comment: You can also draw the a plot for the function f(x) to see that the average is 0.

Comment: @Med when calculating $a_0$ in this way i get 0? Could you show me in the answers the method you use to gain the answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide it two parts and calculate $$a_{ 0 }=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \int _{ -\pi  }^{ \pi  } f\left( x \right) dx=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \int _{ -\pi  }^{ 0 }{ \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } +x \right) dx } +\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \int _{ 0 }^{ \pi  }{ \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } -x \right) dx } =\\ ={ \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } x+\frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ 2 }  \right)  }_{ -\pi  }^{ 0 }{ +\left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } x-\frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ 2 }  \right)  }_{ -\pi  }^{ 0 }=0\\ { a }_{ n }=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \int _{ -\pi  }^{ \pi  } f\left( x \right) \cos { \left( nx \right)  } dx=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \left( \int _{ -\pi  }^{ 0 }{ \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } +x \right) \cos { \left( nx \right)  } dx } +\int _{ 0 }^{ \pi  }{ \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } -x \right) \cos { \left( nx \right)  } dx }  \right) \\ { b }_{ n }=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \int _{ -\pi  }^{ \pi  } f\left( x \right) \sin { \left( nx \right)  } dx=\frac { 1 }{ \pi  } \left( \int _{ -\pi  }^{ 0 }{ \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } +x \right) \sin { \left( nx \right)  } dx } +\int _{ 0 }^{ \pi  }{ \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } -x \right) \sin { \left( nx \right)  } dx }  \right) $$
Can you take from here?